# Logic predicate syntax

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

$ \forall x \exists y F \implies \exists y \forall x F$

My assumption is that F is a predicate F(x, y), so swapping $\forall x$ and $\exists y$ doesn't change the formula, so it's a tautology.

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Why "syntax" ? *Syntax* is about the correct way to write formulas, not about their truth value.

Comment: It's always true that $\exists y\ \forall x\ F \Rightarrow \forall x\ \exists y\ F$, but the converse is not true in general. There are some circumstances when it is, such as when $y$ does not appear in $F$.

Comment: then maybe it's F(void, void), and the lefthand expression is F(x, y) and the righthand is F(y, x)? Then it evaluates to true if F is commutative?

Comment: @jazzandrock No. $F$ is $F$; you can't change variables and say it's still $F$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll correct you!

Consider: $F = P(x,y)$ where $P(x,y)$: '$y$ is the parent of $x$' and domain is people.

Everyone has a parent, sure, but is there a single person that is the parent of everyone? No.

Another example:

$F = x<y$ with domain numbers

For every number we can find a greater number, yes, but is there a number greater than all others? No.